# SQLiteException: unknown database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I made a custom Adapter for my ListView following [this tutorial](https://droidhat.com/android-listview-using-custom-cursoradapter-sqlite-database).
But when I run my app on my device, it gives an error when it's starting.
The error appears when the `onCreate()` method of the MainActivity tries to call the `getData()` method of the NotesDbHelper class.

Can you help me?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;

NotesCustomAdapter notesCustomAdapter = null;
ListView listView = null;
NotesDbHelper database = null;
ArrayList<Notes> notes = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created.
 * @param savedInstanceState */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    database = new NotesDbHelper(this);
    notes = database.getData();
    notesCustomAdapter= new NotesCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.notes_details,notes);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
    listView.setAdapter(notesCustomAdapter);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String input = mEditText.getText().toString();

            if (input.length() > 0) {
            database.insertNote(input);
            }
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    adb.setTitle("Delete?");
    adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
    final int positionToRemove = position;
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            database.deleteNote(which);
            notes.remove(positionToRemove);
            notesCustomAdapter.remove(String.valueOf(positionToRemove));
            notesCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});
    adb.show();
    }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

NotesDbHelper.java

```
public class NotesDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Notes.db";
    public static final String NOTES_TABLE_NAME = "Notes.user";
    public static final String NOTES_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String NOTES_COLUMN_NAME = "n_text";

    public NotesDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table  " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME +
                   "(_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + NOTES_COLUMN_NAME +
                   ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertNote(String text) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("n_text", text);

        db.insert(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Notes> getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ NOTES_TABLE_NAME , null);
        while(result.moveToNext()){
           notes.add( new Notes(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(NOTES_COLUMN_NAME))));

        }
        return notes;
    }

    public boolean updateNotes(int id, int text) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("n_text", text);

        db.update(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteNote(Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(NOTES_TABLE_NAME,
                "id = ? ",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    }

}
```

Notes.java

```
    public class Notes {
    String text;

    public Notes(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

NotesCustomAdapter.java

```
public class NotesCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Notes> notes;

    public NotesCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList objects) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context= context;
        notes=objects;

    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.notes_details, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Notes textNotes = notes.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(textNotes.getText());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

LogCat

the first line says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{agenda.com/agenda.com.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown database Notes (code 1): while compiling: create table Notes.user(_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,n_text)
```

[image]

Comment: Rename `Notes.user` to `Notes_user`since it is not a valid table name.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `Notes.user`? You're putting an unnecessary dot. Go compare to the link you've referenced.

Just use `Notes` or `UserNotes`